# Proof: Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence and $0<q<1$ a constant number s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{a_n}<q$ so $ \lim_{n }a_n=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

*EDIT:* There was a typing error in the question, it is $\sqrt[n]{a_n}<q$ and NOT $\sqrt[n]{a_n}=q$

I/
I have an exercise that say me proof of give a counter exemple of the following statement: Let $a_n$ be a positive sequence and $0<q<1$ a constant number s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{a_n}<q$ so $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_n=0$
I said it was true and here my proof.

II/
**Proof 1:** *Based on Richard Jensen answer*
$0<\sqrt[n]{a_n}<q<1 \Rightarrow 0<a_n<q^n<1$
Now as $0<q<1$ we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }q^n=0$ by using Sandwitch theorem (and remember that $a_n$ is a positive sequence) we have too that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_n=0$ Q.E.D.

**Proof 2:**
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow 0<\sqrt[n]{a_n}<q<1$ so $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow 0<a_n<1$
We know that from every bounded sequence it exists at least one subsequence $a_{n_k}$ that converges.
Now by absurd $\exists l > 0 : \lim_{n_k\rightarrow \infty }a_{n_k}=l$.
Moreover we define $b_{n_k}=\sqrt[n_k]{a_{n_k}}\Rightarrow \lim_{n_k\rightarrow \infty }b_{n_k}=\lim_{n_k\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt[n_k]{a_{n_k}}=\lim_{n_k\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt[n_k]{l}=1$ (by arithmetic of limit).
Contratidiction because in this case it means that it exists an infinity of $n'_{k}$ s.t. $1>b_{n'_k}>q$ in contradiction with the assumption.
So it doesn't exist any subsequence that we can extract from $a_n$ that converges to a limit different of zero. In other words it means that all subsequence that we can extract from $a_n$ converges to zerp (again such subsequence HAVE to exist according to the theorem). Hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }a_n=0$ Q.E.D.

Is this two different proof are correct?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140715/discussion-on-question-by-x0-user-0x-proof-let-a-n-be-a-positive-sequence-and).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument doesn't quite work. If you look at your assumptions about $a_n$, you will see that $b_n = q$ for all $n$, so its limit is $q$ aswell.

As simpler argument would be to notice that $a_n = q^n$. Since $0<q<1$, what can you conclude about the limit?

Comment: Thk for your answer, I made a typing mistake it is $(a^n)^{1/n}<q$ NOT $(a^n)^{1/n}=q$ sorry. In all the cases does my new proof (and so the old one too) worked?

Comment: Up can you tell me if my segond proof is correct?

Comment: The second proof of yours is not correct, see @Anne Bauval's comments.